# Xamarin Studio Mac runtime policy

Tags: visual-studio, xamarin.forms, xamarin-studio

I converted Xamarin.Forms project to .NETStandard 1.5 and when all packages was restored i get warning and all code is crossed

> Warning CS1701: Assuming assembly reference `System.Runtime,
>   Version=4.0.20.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a'
>   matches assembly`System.Runtime, Version=4.1.0.0, Culture=neutral,
>   PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a'. You may need to supply runtime
>   policy (CS1701)

Comment: Same issue here. Using latest Xamarin Studio 6.3 build 864 on Mac. Have you come up with a workaround yet? I haven't despite looking everywhere.